# Failed to register: Unable to acquire bus name 'org.gnome.RemoteDesktop.User'

Tags: gnome, vnc, cinnamon, gnome-control-center

**GNOME remote desktop server on cinnamon.**

`/usr/lib/gnome-remote-desktop-daemon`

> Failed to register: Unable to acquire bus name
> 'org.gnome.RemoteDesktop.User'

I've used CLI `grdctl` to set it up but when running `nmap -p5900 localhost`
the port/s show up closed.

Hence I've tried the easy way and installed GNOME DE, which works "out of the box", the port is open and the daemon is listening.

I suspect a dependency on gnome-control-center.

Is there a way to set this up without the GUI ?